# What does "institutionalize" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I use this link, but I don't think it can help.

Uber will figure out how to deal with its latest crisis, and once again, Kalanick has done the right thing, although we can certainly debate his timing. The larger question is, though, "Will Uber ever learn from its mistakes?" Because if it doesn't, and it perseveres, it will **institutionalize** many of its worst qualities.

Source: http://www.businessinsider.com/Uber-symbolizes-good-and-bad-silicon-valley-2017-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with definition 2 of institution from the [Oxford Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/institution): **An established law or practice**. Plug that into your extract and you get:

> ...it will [make] many of its worst qualities **established practice**.

What this means is that the Uber's worst qualities will define the standard way of doing things within the organisation.

Comment: Or just skip [straight to the definition of 'institutionalize' in the same dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/institutionalize) where it says "Establish (something, typically a practice or activity) as a convention or norm in an organization or culture."